# How to replace/optimize IN with other function?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am selecting data from table `history` and I need to make sure that the rows of `accountid` are equal to `1` and that `customid` is `NULL`, but if it isn't - then I have to check if `customid` is `IN` the list of custom ids that I provide as a `STRING`.

Example:

```
SELECT h.* 
  FROM history h
 WHERE h.accountid = '1' 
   AND IF(h.customid IS NULL,
          h.userid = 100,
          h.customid IN ('1','2','3','4')
          )
```

Here is my problem: the list in which I have to look for customid can be VERY large. Because of this reason my query can run for more than 30 seconds.

How to optimize the `IN` method and are there are any other methods to look for an `id` in a `STRING`list?

Comment: In WHERE clauses, use AND/OR instead of IF/CASE.

Comment: Are you sure that query would even run?  With regards to using `WHERE IN`, MySQL already has some optimizations up its sleeve.  You could consider putting the IDs into a separate table and then indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and/or combo instead of `if`

```
SELECT h.* 
FROM history h
WHERE h.accountid = '1' 
AND ((h.customid IS NULL and h.userid = 100)
or h.customid IN ('1','2','3','4'))
```

Comment: Time it -- I doubt if is any any faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "IN" with "EXISTS".

While "IN" gathers the results and then process those results. "EXISTS" will stop processing everytime he found one condition proven true.

And as said before by @JohnHC and @jarlh:

> you should replace IF or CASE by and/OR.

```
SELECT h.* 
FROM history h
WHERE h.accountid = '1' 
AND ((h.customid IS NULL and h.userid = 100)
or h.customid EXISTS('1','2','3','4'))
```

Luck,

Comment: EXISTS doesn't work like that as far as I know and I have tried using EXISTS like that - did not work.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure there's an index on `customid`, since you're doing lookups on the column.

Secondly, if your list of values is very long, consider batch inserting them into a temporary table (which can have its own indexes) and doing a join instead of `IN`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE target_customid (customid VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY);

-- Insertion can be done as a batch statement, check your database driver
-- for specifics.
INSERT INTO target_customid VALUES('1'),('2'),('3'),('4');

-- Use a left join to check if customid is in the target list
SELECT h.*
FROM history h
LEFT JOIN target_customid t USING(customid)
WHERE h.accountid = '1' AND (t.customid IS NOT NULL OR h.userid = 100);

-- Or use UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM history
WHERE accountid = '1' AND userid = 100
UNION ALL
SELECT h.*
FROM history h JOIN target_customid t USING(customid)
WHERE h.accountid = '1' AND h.userid != 100;

-- Finally, drop the temporary table to prevent conflicts in the same
-- session. The temporary table is automatically dropped at the end of
-- the session, so this step is unnecessary if the session ends here.
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE target_customid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the old trick of turning `OR` into `UNION`:

```
SELECT  h.*
    FROM  history h
    WHERE  h.accountid = '1'
      AND  h.customid IS NULL
      AND  h.userid = 100
 UNION ALL
 SELECT  h.*
    FROM  history h
    WHERE  h.accountid = '1'
      AND  h.customid IN ('1', '2','3','4') )
```

(In the second select, testing for 1/2/... implies `NOT NULL`.)

Then, you need this composite index, with the columns in this order:

```
INDEX(accountid, customid, userid)
```